# How To Fix Intel HAXM Install Error on Window 11 64 bit on i3 4030u

Tags: flutter, android-studio, virtual-machine, android-virtual-device, virtualization

I am using flutter with android studio and trying to setp by AVD but facing few issues, looking for a fix may that I can run my AVD.

**My Laptop specs are** 
i3 4030u 
8GB Ram 
SSD 128 GB 
Intel VTx on (Virtulization on) 
Hyper V Disabled 
Even Credential Gaurd is Disabled 
[Hyper-V is Disbaled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ec9PJ.png) 
[Intel Virtualization is Enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPitz.png)

An error that I am facing while installing **Intel HAXM**
When I tried to install **Intel HAXM** from Android Studio following error comes up

> **Intel® HAXM installation failed. To install Intel® HAXM follow the instructions found at: https://github.com/intel/haxm/wiki/Installation-Instructions-on-Windows**

[HAXM Install Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utiwW.png) 
When I downloaded standalone Intel HAXM Package from Github it shows the following error 
[standalone Intel HAXM Package error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziXEA.png)

> **I Need a solution for this I am tryng to fix it**

Comment: Are you sure that your windows is 64 bit supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From

https://github.com/intel/haxm/wiki/Installation-Instructions-on-Windows#System_Requirements:
It shows that only Windows 10 and 8 & 8.1, 7 64 bit is supported. There is no support for Intel HAXM on Windows 11.
Try running `systeminfo` in cmd. If in Hyper-V requirement everything is yes, then your laptop can support Intel HAXM. For more information go here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/emulator/hardware-acceleration

Also I think you should enable Hyper-V

Comment: For Hyper-V is it recommended to turn on for AVD?

Comment: On Windows 10 October 2018 Update (RS5) and higher, you only need to enable Hyper-V, as it will use Windows Hypervisor Platform (WHPX) automatically. For more details see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?pivots=windows  It says: For the best experience on Windows, it is recommended that you use WHPX to accelerate the Android emulator. If WHPX is not available on your computer, then HAXM can be used.

Answer (score 0):

in my case i was having the same issue to install the HAXM , what i have done is that i've reinstalled android studio and then checked under the Sdk Manager the version of the haxm that is asked to be installed , so i downloaded the same version displayed in Sdk Manager in my case it was intel haxm 7.6.5 , and installed it manually , and it worked :)